# How to get Data info from OpenWeatherMap API 'dt'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I am making a simple react app with **OpenWeatherMap API**.  I need date info from that API to show which day is the current day.  The API returns me a `dt` object I think this is related to date but I can't use it. How can I convert it to a valid date string?  I found a topic [about this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672873/how-to-convert-openweathermap-date-parameter-dt-date) but the answer did not satisfy me.

```
{
"lat": 38.783,
"lon": 41.0466,
"timezone": "Europe/Istanbul",
"timezone_offset": 10800,
"current": {
    "dt": 1610733742,
    "sunrise": 1610685149,
    "sunset": 1610720251,
    "temp": 274.58,
    "feels_like": 270.28,
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.
We can convert to **dt** object to JS date object. Like this.

**The tricky part is we have to convert day object to string.**

```js
    const dt = 1610685149
    
    var day = new Date(dt*1000);
    
    console.log(day.toUTCString()) // 'Fri, 15 Jan 2021 04:32:29 GMT'
    console.log(day.toDateString()) // 'Fri Jan 15 2021'
    console.log(day.toISOString()) // '2021-01-15T04:32:29.000Z'
    console.log(day.toString()) // 'Fri Jan 15 2021 07:32:29 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)'
```

I found the answer from here [**w3schools.com display dates**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

End of the day, I implement this solution to my code just like this.

```js
function createDate(dt, type) {
        var day = new Date(dt * 1000);
        if (type == "long") {
            let options = {
                weekday: "long",
                year: "numeric",
                month: "long",
                day: "numeric",
            };
            return day.toLocaleString("en-us", options); // Friday, January 15, 2021
        } else {
            return day.toLocaleString("en-us", { weekday: "long" }); // Friday
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** I found the more elegant way to convert to string [**from here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40193085/10694425) And also check this [MDN resource about `toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)